# SQL Server --- using raiserror without status accident

Tags: sql-server, raiserror

I wanted to user **RAISERROR** in my SQL-Server codes but I noticed that some status code have interruption with built-in SQL Error statuses...

for example status code "1" is used for "Devide By Zero Error", And I dont wanna use it any more...
now I want to see what status codes are safe to use withour interruption ?

Comment: When you say "status" - do you mean error number, severity, state, or error level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your own msgid use a value of greater then 50000. The values below 50000 are reserved for built in messages. To see the list of existing messages you can do a 'select * from sys.messages'. 50000 is used when a value for msgid is not provided.